# Modulo $x^y \pmod n$ correctly??

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I have an RSA example to solve. I got my decryption key and now I need to calculate the modulo $d^e \pmod n$. Here is the example

$$ 1007^{10} \mod 3599.
$$

What I am trying is 
$$
1007^3 \times 3 = 3063442029 + 1007^1 = 3063443036.
$$

Then I am trying to get the mod by $3063443036/3599$ but that does not give me the answer I get $851192.8413$ while the modulo should be $441$.

I don't think I am doing the calculations correctly  in this part
$$
1007^3 \times 3 = 3063442029 + 1007^1 = 3063443036.
$$

Comment: Can you explain why you were doing this calculation: $1007^3 * 3 = 3063442029 + 1007^1 = 3063443036$?

Comment: 1007^10 wont render in my calculator so i tried to break it down, whats the altenrative?

Comment: You can represent it as a product of squares, as in: $(1007^2)^3 * 1007^2$. Remember that since $1007^2 \equiv 2730 \pmod {3599}$, you can instead calculate $3599^3$ rather than $(1007^2)^3$.

Comment: @WojtekT maybe try modular exponentiation through Euler's theorem or Fermat's little theorem ? just a thought of possible ways to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one of the simplest ways to do it:

We can represent $1007^{10}$ as a product of $1007^8 * 1007^2$, or $(1007^2)^3 * 1007^2$.

Since $1007^2 \equiv -869 \pmod {3599}$, you can use $-869$ instead of $1007^2$ to calculate $(-869)^3$, which is equivalent to $-447$. Since we have already calculated $1007^2$ ($-869$), multiply $-447*-869$ and compute the result modulo $3599$.

If you really want a faster result than this, go to [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/).

Comment: Thanks for the anwser but im still confused where are you getting the -896 from?

Comment: Do you know what modular arithmetic is? Basically speaking, it is the remainder when you divide by some number. $1007^2 \equiv 2730 \pmod {3599}$, but since subtracting by some multiple of $3599$ will still give the same remainder, so what I did was to do $2730 - 3599*1 = -869$.

Comment: @WojtekT equivalent representatives.

Comment: Kind, of. I need to know how to calculate it it would be 1007^2/3599? I havent done this in ages, and cant find any examples

Comment: no that would be a quotient.

Comment: By calculator you can calculate $1007^2/3599$, then subtract the integer part, and then multiply by $3599$.

Comment: Oh god, Im such a doneky, Thank you i know what to do know! :)